# How to write a complete solution set for $x$ in trigonometry questions?

Tags: trigonometry

Should I be able to perform this operation?
$$\cos 3x=1\Rightarrow3x=\cos^{-1}1\Rightarrow \bbox[yellow,5px]{x=\frac{\cos^{-1}1}3}$$

Well it gives a right answer because $\cos (3\times0)=1$, but I do understand that it does not give all the answers.

Using mathematica, it tells me that the complete set of solutions is:
$$x\rightarrow\frac{2\pi}3\cdot C, \ \ \ \mathbb{for \ }C\in\mathbb{Z}$$

### Additionally

How do I write the conditional expression that defines all the answer for any trigonometry question? Does it help that I should be working in radians? Or is it solvable when working in degrees to?

Comment: Well, handling angles (either in degrees or in radian) is always *periodic* to $360^\circ\ $ ($2\pi$), so that you could write $3c=\cos^{-1}1\,+k\cdot360^\circ$, and then dividing by $3$ will give all the solutions.

Comment: So for every trig question, the solution set should always contain $+k\cdot360^\circ$ or $+k\cdot2\pi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General solution of trigonomertic equations:

$\cos x=\cos \theta$ $\implies$ $x=2n\pi\pm\theta$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\tan x=\tan\theta$ $\implies$ $x=n\pi+\theta$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\sin x=\sin\theta$ $\implies$ $x=n\pi+(-1)^n\theta$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

For this question,

\begin{align*}
&\;\cos 3x=1\\
\implies &\;\cos 3x=\cos0\\
\implies &\; 3x=2n\pi\pm 0=2n\pi \quad(n\in\mathbb{Z})\\
\implies &\; x=\frac{2n\pi}{3} \quad(n\in\mathbb{Z})\\
\end{align*}

Comment: For $\sin x = \sin \theta$, we have $x = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $x = \pi - \theta + 2m\pi = (2m + 1)\pi - \theta, m \in \mathbb{Z}$.   Thus, $x = n\pi + (-1)^n\theta, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes. I forgot to delete the '2'' after copy-and-paste. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is *much* simpler to use the language of congruences:
$$\cos 3x=1\iff3x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv 0\mod\frac{2\pi}3.$$

The unit is unrelated to solving or not. This being said, the natural unit, mathematically speaking, is the radian.